# Lser of capacitor not equivalent to a separate inductor in LTspice?

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, resonance

I just noticed a strange issue in LTspice and I am wondering what I am doing wrong. This is about capacitors with series resistance and inductance:

**Example 1:** A simple bandpass. Behavior seems ok.

[image]

**Example 2:** same circuit ?! The cap C1 has Lser=1n. Behavior is different

[image]

**Why?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like just by adding Lser=1n inductance the LTspcie decided (by default) to add some parallel capacitance.

\$C_{par} \approx \frac{1}{4\pi^2F^2 * L} \approx\frac{1}{4*\pi^2*16GHz^2*1nH} \approx 0.0989pF\$

To check this try to set Cpar=0 in LTspcie.

Comment: Yes. That was the reason. In fact, ignoring the parallel capacitance is probably a greater problem for some circuits (in terms of realism and convergence), which is why they added it in the first place.

Comment: There's also `rlshunt` to account for, though I don't see its effects here. Though `Rpar` for the inductor, alone, might be, since its value is `L/Gmin` (so for `1n` it's `1n/1T=1k`). `Rlshunt` is probably the same.